# Network adapter blocks connections after 1 hour

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services, rdp, windows-firewall

Recently imported a Windows 2008 R2 standard server into AWS EC2

Windows firewall is enabled and RDP etc functions ok through it.

After exactly 1 hour all network traffic is blocked.

Rebooting the server allows another 1 hour of network access.

I am confused as to what is causing this 1 hour block!

Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, you're saying you can no longer establish new connections, and can no longer use any existing connections, after 1 hour?  Nothing in the logs? (Sorry... uh... "event viewer?")  Does EC2 continue to show the instance as passing both health checks?  Is it pingable?

Comment: Check out TCP View https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437 and see if something is using up all or your available ports